# rails validates_uniqueness_of not working as it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have an account model like so

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I had some duplicates records on it in production so I've added this line to it

```
validates_uniqueness_of :owner_id, :on => :create
```

so it will only verify this on new records and **NOT** on `save!`

it works on localhost and even on console on production. 
but I have a job that runs every 10 minutes that uses rails runner and it fails for

```
Validation failed: Owner has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

The runner does some actions on accounts and then saves them.

am I doing something wrong on this syntax ?

Comment: Updated in the question - The runner does some actions on accounts and then saves them.

Answer (score 0):

Only time I've seen this happen was when a controller "create" action was being sent as a :get request (instead of :post as it should be in REST). The result was the validation didn't realize it was doing a :create. Doesn't sound like what you've got here... but maybe similar? 
FYI my fix at the time was to use `if: :new_record?` instead of `on: :create` until the request type could be fixed. You could try this.

Also, you can put a debug statement into the validation to interrogate the state of the object during that validation with e.g. `if: -> { binding.pry }` or `if: -> { debugger }` (depending on what you use to debug with, of course). Hopefully that will help figure out what the runner is doing different. You can ask the object if it's a `new_record?` or what `changes` it has to save, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this method has no 
:on => :create 
only :if 
so I've did this:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :owner_id, :if =>  Proc.new { |account| account.created_at > Time.now - 10.seconds }
```